# Integration with google search result

Tags: php

I want to build a system in which the user enters a website domain and a word, and the system shows in which place he is located.

How can I get the search result from Google? there is any way? I am working with PHP and JavaScript.

Comment: Are you asking how to perform a generic Google search programmatically, or are you asking how to perform the kind of search you describe in the first paragraph? If it's the latter, please describe your system in more detail. Your existing description is not clear.

Answer (score -1):

Google [does not provide](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Toolbar/thread?tid=0070f5c7b391c078) a public API for querying the ranking (PageRank) of a page.

You could perform the query yourself and check the results against the domain you're looking for, but unless you look only to the first pages, it becomes unfeasible.

As to how to perform Google searches programmatically, see the [Custom Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html).